# How to change whole page in AngularJS using routing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in AngularJS. I have used simple routing to change specific part of data this case is working fine and in this case I want to change whole page data without refreshing page. Here a last li name `Change Full Page` I want on click third li whole page data should be change without refreshing the page.

routing.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
<ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#/AddNewStudent"> Add New Student </a></li>
        <li><a href="#/ShowStudents"> Show Student </a></li>
        <li><a href="#/changepage"> Change Full Page </a></li>

</ul>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', []);
    sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                .when('/AddNewStudent',{
                    templateUrl : 'addnewstudents.html',
                    controller : 'AddNewStudentController'
                })
                .when('/ShowStudents',{
                    templateUrl : 'showStudents.html',
                    controller : 'showStudentsController'
                })
                .when('/changepage',{
                    templateUrl : 'changepage.html',
                    controller : 'changepageController'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/AddNewStudent'
                  });
        }]);
    sampleApp.controller('AddNewStudentController',function($scope){
        $scope.message = "Please Add New Student ";
    });
    sampleApp.controller('showStudentsController',function($scope){
        $scope.message1 = 'Show All Students';
    });
    sampleApp.controller('changepageController',function($scope){
        $scope.message2 = 'Change Whole Page';
    });
</script>
</html>
```

addnewstudents.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{message}}
</body>
</html>
```

showStudents.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{message1}}
</body>
</html>
```

changepage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
{{message2}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the whole page using angularjs route. The angular js `$routeProvider` only target the `ng-view` placeholder, and replace the content (innerHtml) of ng-view div with the once coming back from templateUrl define in route config.

Therefore your templateUrl should return only partial view only. Means it should not contain    tag. Also the angular reference is already loaded in parent view so ne need to load it in each partial view.

Sample addnewstudents.html --

```
<h2>Add Student<h2>
{{message}}
```

Comment: first thanks for reply but there is any option to change whole page without refresh the page any idea ???

Comment: if you want to refresh whole page, then instead of route use $window.location.href or remove # from the anchor link and call templateUrl directly.

Comment: The $routeProvider and ng-view use specially when you want to create Single Page application.

Comment: but it will refresh the page and i want to create single page application.

Comment: then you have to use partial view as i mentioned above. Also it's not correct to load script reference with every ajax call

Comment: To develop a single page app. For reference i'll recommend you to have a look at Angular Hot Towel : https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel-Angular

Comment: but my view is not a partial it`s full new view..how can i do that.suppose that i am using bracket theme first i have to login then after login i will redirect on dashboard page then how could be possible to go on dashboard page after login without refreshing page ??